# Phpunit mock uuid

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am writing unit test for manager class which can persist data into database with usage of repository. I want to assert that repository method `save()` is called with given data. In this case it is Entity object called `Instance` which has few standard fields and uuid. But when running this test phpunit is telling me that `Instance` object I've provided in test has different uuid from object that is beeing send as argument in the invoked method. So my problem is that i know where error comes from but i don't have idea how to fix it.

```php
class InstanceManagerTest extends TestCase
{
    private InstanceManager $instanceManager;
    private CreateInstance $createInstanceDto;
    private Instance $instanceEntity;
    private MockObject $instanceRepositoryMock;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->instanceManager = new InstanceManager(
            $this->instanceRepositoryMock = self::createMock(InstanceRepositoryInterface::class)
        );

        $this->createInstanceDto = new CreateInstance(
            new CreateAddress(
                'asd',
                'asd',
                'asd',
                'asd',
                'asd'
            ),
            'asd',
            'asd',
            'asd',
            'asd'
        );

        $this->updateInstanceDto = new UpdateInstance(
            new UpdateAddress(
                'asd',
                'asd',
                'asd',
                'asd',
                'asd',
                Uuid::v4()
            ),
            'asd',
            'asd',
            'asd',
            'asd',
            Uuid::v4()
        );

        $this->instanceEntity = new Instance(
            $this->createInstanceDto->name,
            $this->createInstanceDto->nip,
            $this->createInstanceDto->regon,
            $this->createInstanceDto->krs,
            new Address($this->createInstanceDto->address)
        );


    }

    /** @test */
    public function create_validArguments_returnsInstancePresenter()
    {
        // Here I expect that method save() of Instance repository will be called once with same object InstanceEntity
        $this->instanceRepositoryMock->expects(
            $this->once())->method('save')->with($this->instanceEntity);

        $result = $this->instanceManager->create($this->createInstanceDto);

        // Assert
        self::assertInstanceOf(InstancePresenter::class, $result);
    }
}
```

```php
class InstanceManager
{
    public function __construct(private readonly InstanceRepositoryInterface $repository)
    {
    }

    public function create(CreateInstance $dto): InstancePresenter
    {
        return InstancePresenter::fromEntity($this->repository->save(
        // Here when I create Instance it sets all fields form dto except uuid which is beeing generated
            new Instance(
                $dto->name,
                $dto->nip,
                $dto->regon,
                $dto->krs,
                new Address(
                    $dto->address
                )
            )
        ));
    }
//...
}
```

```php
class Instance
{
    private readonly ?int $id;

    private Uuid $instanceId;

    private string $name;

    private string $nip;

    private string $regon;

    private string $krs;

    private Address $address;

    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $deletedAt = null;

    public function __construct(string $name, string $nip, string $regon, string $krs, Address $address)
    {
        $this->instanceId = Uuid::v4();
        $this->update($name, $nip, $regon, $krs, $address);
    }

    public function update(string $name, string $nip, string $regon, string $krs, Address $address): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->nip = $nip;
        $this->regon = $regon;
        $this->krs = $krs;
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }
//...
}
```